# How to get common models out of two many to many relationships in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

There are 3 Models :

```
Products belongstoMany Categories
Products belongstoMany Stores
Categories belongstoMany Products
Stores belongstoMany Products
```

How to find all Products which belong to a particular category and a particular store?

This is what I've tried:

```
Product::getAll()->join('categorie_product', 'categorie_product.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
                ->join('categorie', 'categorie.id', '=', 'categorie_product.categorie_id')
                ->where('categorie.name', '=', $categorieName)
                ->paginate(10);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks..

P.S.: I want to use eloquent for this task. DB::* will do but I need eloquent implementation because I am using Dingo API to get some REST APIs done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereHas` to filter by a relation:

```
Product::with('categorie','store')->whereHas('categorie', function($q) use ($categoryName){
                        $q->where('categories.name', $categoryName);
                    })->whereHas('store', function($q) use ($storeId){
                        $q->where('stores.id', $storeId);
                    })->paginate(10);
```

Also don't forget to [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) your related models using `with()`

Comment: Works, like a charm! Edited this to include with(). Thanks!  
Lots of thanks for suggesting eager load :)